# Optimization of two for-loops

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the following code:

```
error1 = 0
    for point1 in p1:
        min_dist = 1000000000
        for point2 in p2:
            min_dist = min(min_dist, l2(point1, point2))
        error1 += min_dist
```

While p1,p2 are arrays of 2D points ([x,y])

l2 is: np.linalg.norm(np.array(p1) - np.array(p2))

Comment: Hi! Kindly ask you to provide a reproducible example (including some inputs and outputs) so that people willing to help may try things easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume p1 has N points, p2 has M points.

```
import numpy as np

pt1 = np.array(p1)  # NxD, here D=2
pt2 = np.array(p2)  # MxD
d = pt1[:, None, :] - pt2[None, :, :]  # pairwise subtraction, NxMxD
d = np.sum(d**2, axis=2).min(axis=1)  # min square distance, N
error1 = np.sqrt(d).sum()  # output, scalar
```